# LaTeX failed to compile stack.tex

Tags: r-markdown

I'm trying to export my Rmarkdown document as a .pdf file. When I use knit to export my .Rmd file, the output process failed for the math formula inside and I receive the following error message:

```
output file: stack.knit.md

! Package amsmath Error: \begin{align*} allowed only in paragraph mode.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile stack.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See stack.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

The math formula I wrote in  .Rmd is :

```
$\\begin{align\*} E\[X\] &= \\int\_{-\\infty}^{\\infty} xf(x) {\\rm d}x \\ &= \\int\_{-\\infty}^{1} 0x {\\rm d}x + \\int\_{1}^{e} \\frac{1}{x}x {\\rm d}x + \\int\_{e}^{\\infty} 0x {\\rm d}x \\ &= \\int\_{1}^{e} 1 {\\rm d}x \\&= x\\big|^{e}\_{1} \\&= (e - 1)\\end{align\*}$

$\\begin{align\*} E\[X^2\] &= \\int\_{-\\infty}^{\\infty} x^2f(x) {\\rm d}x \\ &= \\int\_{-\\infty}^{1} 0x^2 {\\rm d}x + \\int\_{1}^{e} \\frac{1}{x}x^2 {\\rm d}x + \\int\_{e}^{\\infty} 0x^2 {\\rm d}x \\ &= \\int\_{1}^{e} x {\\rm d}x \\ &= \\frac{1}{2}x^2\\big|^{e}\_{1} \\ &= \\frac{1}{2}(e^2 - 1) \\end{align\*}$
```

It works on Rmarkdown visual but cannot be exported.

Could you please help me to fix this error?